# Comparing values of 2 xml files and echoing match

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to use 2 xml files to put data on to a list. One Xml file is not editable by me the 2nd is a reference database of sorts that I created. Both files have a common string for `<rvXMLfilename>` and if both xml file strings match I want to echo out a string from XML file 2. I attmepted to write this in my php script but I could not get it to work.

```
$railunit = simplexml_load_file('railUnitList.xml');
$orders = simplexml_load_file('train.xml');

    foreach ($orders->xpath("//RailVehicleStateClass") as $traininfo):
    $rvXMLfilename=$traininfo->rvXMLfilename;
    $unitType=$traininfo->unitType;
    $unitNumber=$traininfo->unitNumber;
    $destinationTag=$traininfo->destinationTag;
    $loadWeightUSTons=$traininfo->loadWeightUSTons;

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    if($railunit->rvXMLfilename == $orders->rvXMLfilename){
        echo $railunit->unitType;
    }else{
        echo "error!";
    }
```

XML File 1

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ScnLoader xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <trainList>
    <TrainLoader>
      <unitLoaderList>
        <RailVehicleStateClass>
          <rvXMLfilename>R8_SD40T-2_UP03.xml</rvXMLfilename>
          <unitType>US_DieselEngine</unitType>
          <loadWeightUSTons>14.2985783</loadWeightUSTons>
          <destinationTag>MDTLA</destinationTag>
          <unitNumber>8626</unitNumber>
        </RailVehicleStateClass>
        <RailVehicleStateClass>
          <rvXMLfilename>R8_SD40T-2_UP01.xml</rvXMLfilename>
          <unitType>US_DieselEngine</unitType>
          <loadWeightUSTons>14.2985792</loadWeightUSTons>
          <destinationTag>None</destinationTag>
          <unitNumber>4401</unitNumber>
        </RailVehicleStateClass>
        <RailVehicleStateClass>
          <rvXMLfilename>R8_SD40T-2_UP01.xml</rvXMLfilename>
          <unitType>US_DieselEngine</unitType>
          <loadWeightUSTons>14.2985783</loadWeightUSTons>
          <destinationTag>None</destinationTag>
          <unitNumber>4454</unitNumber>
        </RailVehicleStateClass>
      </unitLoaderList>
    </TrainLoader>
  </trainList>
</ScnLoader>
```

XML File 2

```
<railUnitList>
  <railUnit>
    <rvXMLfilename>R8_SD40T-2_UP01.xml</rvXMLfilename>
    <unitType>SD40-2T Locomotive</unitType>
    <reportingMark>UP</reportingMark>
    <axelCount>6</axelCount>
    <unitWeight></unitWeight>
    <unitLength>71</unitLength>
  </railUnit>
  <railUnit>
    <rvXMLfilename>R8_CoveredHopper_ACF2970_BN01.xml</rvXMLfilename>
    <unitType>Covered Hopper</unitType>
    <reportingMark>BN</reportingMark>
    <axelCount>4</axelCount>
    <unitWeight></unitWeight>
    <unitLength>60</unitLength>
  </railUnit>
  <railUnit>
    <rvXMLfilename>R8_C14Hopper_POTASH01.xml</rvXMLfilename>
    <unitType>Covered Hopper</unitType>
    <reportingMark>POTX</reportingMark>
    <axelCount>4</axelCount>
    <unitWeight></unitWeight>
    <unitLength>60</unitLength>
  </railUnit>
  <railUnit>
    <rvXMLfilename>Run8_Tank107BN01.xml</rvXMLfilename>
    <unitType>Tank</unitType>
    <reportingMark>BN</reportingMark>
    <axelCount>4</axelCount>
    <unitWeight></unitWeight>
    <unitLength>59</unitLength>
  </railUnit>
</railUnitList>
```

Comment: `$railunit->rvXMLfilename`. Is `rvXMLfilename` a direct child of the root element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code. Firstly you cannot directly refer to the value of a `SimpleXMLElement` as e.g. `$rvXMLfilename=$traininfo->rvXMLfilename`; you need to cast it to the appropriate type. Secondly `rvXMLfilename` is not a child of `$railunit`. I think you probably want to iterate through the values in your `$railunit`, comparing each of them with the values you extract from the `$orders` XML. This code should achieve what you want:

```
foreach ($orders->xpath("//RailVehicleStateClass") as $traininfo) {
    $rvXMLfilename=(string)$traininfo->rvXMLfilename;
    $unitType=(string)$traininfo->unitType;
    $unitNumber=(int)$traininfo->unitNumber;
    $destinationTag=(string)$traininfo->destinationTag;
    $loadWeightUSTons=(float)$traininfo->loadWeightUSTons;
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    $message = "error!";
    foreach ($railunit->railUnit as $ru) {
        if((string)$ru->rvXMLfilename == $rvXMLfilename){
            $message = (string)$ru->unitType;
        }
    }
    echo $message;
}
```

Output (for your sample data)

```
<tr><td>error!<tr><td>SD40-2T Locomotive<tr><td>SD40-2T Locomotive
```

Answer (score 0):

Again use the XPath query to get the values you're looking for. Stick all the filenames into an array, for easier comparison later.

```
<?php
$railunit = simplexml_load_file('railUnitList.xml');
$orders = simplexml_load_file('train.xml');

foreach ($railunit->railUnit as $railunit) {
    $key = (string)$railunit->unitType;
    $value = (string)$railunit->rvXMLfilename;
    $filenames[$key] = $value;
}

foreach ($orders->xpath("//RailVehicleStateClass") as $traininfo) {
    $rvXMLfilename=$traininfo->rvXMLfilename;
    $unitType=$traininfo->unitType;
    $unitNumber=$traininfo->unitNumber;
    $destinationTag=$traininfo->destinationTag;
    $loadWeightUSTons=$traininfo->loadWeightUSTons;

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    if(in_array($traininfo->rvXMLfilename, $filenames)){
        echo array_search($traininfo->rvXMLfilename, $filenames);
    } else {
        echo "error!";
    }
}
```

Note also your use of `$orders->rvXMLfilename` in the original code. The PHP structure is the same as the XML structure, you can't reference an element in that fashion unless it's the direct child of the root element.